# Cannot resolve import io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.annotation.MicronautTest dependency on micronaut 1.3.7

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, spock, micronaut

I want to add spock testing framework in micronaut but so I added these dependencies in micronaut:

```
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
```

But when I am trying to import `io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.annotation.MicronautTest` it is not getting resolved. I also tried clean build.

And I also tried deleting JUnit dependencies from the build.gradle. But this dependency is not being resolved.

Comment: What error messages do you get in the build console output? can you add this to the question please? Unrelated question: Are you aware that Micronaut 1.3.7 is extremely old? Don't you have the possibility to upgrade to at least 2.5.x or even jump onto the latest 3.7 release train? I guess 1.3.x isn't supported anymore

Comment: The problem is I can't even import MicronatuTest from this package io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock here, and I used same dependencies in 2.5.x it worked, I am curious if there is any possible way to add spock in this micronaut version @saw303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Micronaut 1.3.7 the version of `io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock` should be 1.1.2. The class `io.micronaut.test.extensions.spock.annotation.MicronautTest` didn't exist at that time.

Based on the [1.3.7 Documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.3.7/guide/), looks like it should be `io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest`.

**Update:**

Created a Micronaut 1.3.7 project.

```
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest // !!!

@MicronautTest
class DemoTest extends Specification {
}
```

**Notice the import package.**

For completeness here were the test dependencies created by the `mn` cli.

```
testImplementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
   exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
}
testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
```

Not sure if all are needed and didn't create an actual test case nor did I run the sample application.

Comment: I generated the test via micronaut cli as I was not sure how spock tests will be written on version 1.3.7, it generated the `@MicronautTest` annotation with this pacakge `io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock`

Comment: @suvodipMondal Updated my answer for clarification.